# Remove nth character from a string variable in Linux bash shellscript

Tags: bash, shell

I have seen many methods for removing some characters based on regular string or special match using tr etc. But I didn't find any way to delete a character based on accurate index in a string.

For example: In `var="hello world"`,I want to delete the 5th char 'o' and then var should be like `"hell world"`. The code should apply to all other normal strings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
n=5
var="hello world"
var=${var:0:n-1}${var:n}
```